# How to handle an unknown number of futures that depend on the previous result?

Tags: scala

I have a method that makes an API call and returns a `Future[Seq[Post]]`, with each post having a sequential `id`.  The API call returns 200 posts per call.  In order to get a complete sequence of posts, I submit the smallest `id` (as `maxId`) in subsequent calls.  Each `Post` object also contains a `User` object that contains a field specifying the total number of posts made by the user.  What's the best way to accomplish getting all of a user's posts in a non-blocking manner?

Thus far, I have the following blocking code:

```
def completeTimeline(userId: Long) = {
  def getTimeline(maxId = Option[Long] = None): Seq[Post] = {
    val timeline: Future[Seq[Post]] = userPosts(userId) // calls method that returns Future[Seq[Post]]
    Await.result(timeline, 5.seconds)
}

  def recurseTimeline(timeline: Seq[Post]): Seq[Post] = {
    if (timeline.length < timeline.head.user.map(user => user.post_count).getOrElse(0)) {
      val maxId = timeline.min(Ordering.by((p: Post) => p.id)).id - 1 // API call with maxId is inclusive, subtract 1 to avoid duplicates
      val nextTimeline = getTimeline(maxId = Some(maxId))
      val newTimeline = timeline ++ nextTimeline
      recurseTimeline(newTimeline)
    } else timeline
  }
  recurseTimeline(getTimeline())
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def completeTimeline(userId: Long): Future[Seq[Post]] = {

  def getTimeline(maxId: Option[Long] = None): Future[Seq[Post]] = {
    val timeline: Future[Seq[Post]] = userPosts(userId) // calls method that returns Future[Seq[Post]]
    timeline
  }

  def recurseTimeline(timeline: Seq[Post]): Future[Seq[Post]] = {
    if (timeline.length < timeline.head.user.map(user => user.post_count).getOrElse(0)) {
      val maxId = timeline.min(Ordering.by((p: Post) => p.id)).id - 1 // API call with maxId is inclusive, subtract 1 to avoid duplicates
      for {
        nextTimeline <- getTimeline(maxId = Some(maxId))
        full <- recurseTimeline(timeline ++ nextTimeline)
      } yield full
    } else Future.successful(timeline)
  }

  getTimeline() flatMap recurseTimeline
}
```

Essentially, you are *scheduling* things to happen once each future completes (map, flatMap, and for-comprehension), instead of waiting for them to complete.

The code can probably be simplified if i understood a bit better what you're trying to do.

Comment: This works, thanks.  I guess I was a bit vague in my original post.  Let's say a user has 800 posts.  One API call can retrieve a maximum of 200 posts.  To get the next 200, I need to supply a maximum value (maxId) for the post's ID.  An API call without a maxId gets the most recent 200 posts: [API-call-1]: (postId: 800, 799, 798, 797, 796 ... 600); [API-call-2, maxId: 599]: (postId: 599, 598, 597, 596 ... 399].  In order to get the maxId, I need the value of [API-call-1], so I can't make the next API call until the previous one completes.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `non-blocking` that is incompatible with `I need to check all of the Posts`: you do need to wait for all of the Futures to complete - and thus be able to find the minimum `id` before proceeding.  Correct? or would you like to further explain your intent?

Proceeding on that assumption - you can add each of the Future's to a list and then iterate on the list and calling Await on each one.  This is in fact the standard blocking mechanism for obtaining a set of futures.

If there were further considerations and/or assumptions being made then please provide them - to allow tweaking this general approach for your particulars.